# How to limit my api result with edamam API

Tags: kotlin, httprequest, edamam-api

I am trying to make a call to the edamam API to just get 1 item, right now when I call it I get a lot of results which I don't need, is there a query I can use to limit the results?

I have tried to put maxResults at the end but id doesn't change my response

```
https://api.edamam.com/api/food-database/v2/parser?session=40&app_id=$id&app_key=$appKey&ingr=rice&maxResults=1
```

Comment: There isn't a way to limit the response, what I've done is to get the results in a List and use just the first with .first(), not the most efficient way of doing things but it works

Answer (score 0):

The [official documentation](https://developer.edamam.com/food-database-api-docs#/) does not name any means to actively influence the result set / page size of the result.
There is an OpenAPI specification [available](https://api.edamam.com/doc/open-api/food-db-v2.json) as well.

There seems to be basic support for pagination, however that is solely based on a session and only supports iteration instead of full control of which page to request and of which size a page should be.

> To obtain the next page, the API user should follow the “next” link from the “_links” section in the result JSON ...

The `/auto-complete` endpoint allows to provide a `limit` parameter. However, that does not seem to be supported by the `/api/food-database/v2/parser` endpoint you're interested in.

Comment: That is what I thought but nevertheless thank you very much